# Ubuntu Software Center - unable to see installed software

Tags: software-center

I use Ubuntu Software Center without any significant problems with installing/unistalling any software. But then something happened (may be during some unsccessful installation) and then I can't access the list of installed programs in Ubuntu Software Center.

Comment: have you tried re-installing it ?

Answer (score 0):

open your terminal with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and type as

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall software-center
```

hope that helps.

Comment: Even after reinstallation the SW center crashes with message "The application SWC has closed unexpetedly". Other functions work well. I "only" cant open installed software

Comment: You mean other users can ?